# Cleaning up C# code

Tags: c#

Is there any tool that cleans up C#.NET code of all the comments, debug statements, documentation when deploying it to a server?

I am looking to use this for deployment scenarios...and hopefully should be able to integrate this with CruiseControl.NET or even TFSBuild.

Thanks in advance.

- SK

Comment: I probably don't understand the situation or context (honestly), but why do you need to do this? When c# is compiled, the comments are literally ignored, and the .exe is no larger size. I'm confused, what is the motivation?

Comment: Just curious as to why you want to remove comments.

Comment: Why do you want to clean this up?  The compiler ignores it anyway, and the comments, etc aren't copied into the produced dll's anyway, are they?

Comment: Building in release mode will remove most of what you want; I don't see why 'documentation' is even included in your build process, if you don't want it.

Comment: Yes, it'c called a compiler. It's built into your C# IDE.

Comment: I would want to see it for readability. I have seen lots of code where documentation comments like /// Constructor for class ABCD or /// Code behind for abcd.xaml kind of lnes that makes it problematic to read and understand the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a release build - that will remove all of those things.

Answer (score 8):

There is no reason to do this.  Comments, debug statements, and documentation are ignored by the compiler, so if you're deploying using MS-Build, there is no point to this.

Answer (score 6):

**Comments**: They are ignored by default

**debug statement**: As long as you compile your code in release mode, all the `Debug.Assert` are ignored.

**documentation** : same with comments

Answer (score 1):

When your code is 'built' the compiler will generate a binary image CLI instructions.  No commets will be present, they are ignored.

To remove debug statements, build in release mode.

If you are worried about people [reversing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_engineering#Reverse_engineering_of_software) your code, you should consider [obfuscation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code) to make it more difficult.

Comment: +1 although obfuscation will only make it more difficult, but not that much so.

Comment: Yeah, obfuscation is a female dog, especially when you're doing reflection and/or implementing services with named endpoints etc. bleh

Answer (score 0):

Release Build - nt